# Доступ к MySQL и FireBird одновременно

Tags: mysql, yii2, firebird

Всем привет) Сразу говорю, я новичок который начал изучать фреймворк YII2 неделю назад) Так получилось что после универа без опыта и знаний попал на работу, где есть функционирующий сайт на YII2 с БД MySQL. Мне поставили задачу написать к существующему сайту пару страниц, которые будут выводить данные из БД FireBird. Как мне создать дополнительное подключение к БД FireBird? Я не смог найти как это сделать. Может кто рассказать как это сделать и дать небольшой пример всего этого?

Comment: Для начала всегда хорошо обратиться к документации http://firebirdsql.org/manual/ru/qsg15-databases-ru.html

Comment: К этому обращался, это не то. Тут дело в самом фреймворке. Каким образом реализовать это на нем? Потому что фреймворк этот очень капризничает с данной бд.

Comment: *Вот статья, которая помогла мне это реализовать:* https://habrahabr.ru/post/283222/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступ к базе данных Firebird из YII2 можно осуществить с помощью одного из расширений. Первое [yii2-firebirddb от Sergey Rusakov](https://github.com/srusakov/yii2-firebirddb), второе [yii2-firebird от Edgard Lorraine Messias](https://github.com/edgardmessias/yii2-firebird). Я осуществил с помощью второго. Устанавливал расширение через composer. Для этого нужно открыть файл composer.json в основной папке проекта и добавить следующую строку в поле:

```
"require": {
    ....
    "edgardmessias/yii2-firebird": "*"
    ....
```

После чего выполняем 2 команды в консоли по очереди:

```
composer update
composer install
```

После установки открываем файл main.php или main-local.php и прописываем новое подключение:

```
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'edgardmessias\db\firebird\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'firebird:dbname=123.123.123.123:FDB;charset=WIN1251',
        'username' => 'SYSDBA',
        'password' => 'masterkey'
    ],
```

В кратце о строке: `'dsn' => 'firebird:dbname=ip адрес:название базы данных;charset=WIN1251',`

И все, подключение готово. Более подробную инструкцию можете найти на GitHub по ссылкам выше.